# Disable input element based on PHP variable value

Tags: php, html

How would I disable specific input elements based on the value of a PHP variable?

**Example HTML**

```
<?php 

$stock_count = 1; 

?>

<td width="252" valign="top">
          <a href="action-sale.php?size=<?=$size_quantity?>_con_b&amp;id=<?=$product['product_id'];?>&barcode=<?=$barcode?>&shop_price=<?=$product['price']?>&amp;brand=<?=$product['brand_id']?>&amp;title=<?=$product['title']?>">
          <input name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green"
                 id="sale" value="CONCESSION PRODUCT SOLD" style="width:100%" onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <a href="action-delivery.php?size=<?=$size_quantity?>_con_b&amp;id=<?=$product['product_id'];?>&barcode=<?=$barcode?>">
              <input name="button" type="submit" class="submit-button"
                     id="delivery" value="PRODUCT DELIVERED" style="width:170px" onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>
              </a>
        </td>
```

**Condition**

```
    IF ($stock_count <= 0) 
{
    Disable ID 'Sale' 
}
ELSE IF ($stock_count > 0) 
{
    Do not disable anything
}
```

So based on the condition above the `disabled` attribute would be added to the `sale` input button. If the value of the `$stock_count` variable is greater than 0 than no action will be needed.

Any advice appreciated. 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I managed to solve the issue with the following code:

```
 $disabled = $stock_count > 0 ? "" : "disabled";

 <input name="sale" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" 
                 id="sale" value="PRODUCT SOLD" style="width:100%"
                 onclick="location.href='action-sale.php'"; <?php echo $disabled; ?> />
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: why have you tagged your question with javascript and jquery? According to your description, you only need php. Is there something else going on?

Comment: @andrew - I was expecting an answer that involved javascript when I posted the question initially. Now changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 

    $stock_count = 1; 
    $disabled = $stock_count > 0 ? "disabled='disabled'" : "";

?>

<input name="button5" type="submit" id="sale" ... <?php echo $disabled; ?> />
```

Just echo the attribute or an empty string based on a condition.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't seem to be getting the expected result as the inputs are still enabled when the condition is true. Please see my update above - any advice?

Comment: You'll have to look at the outputted HTML and make sure it's valid, and that you're getting what you're expecting. This is the way to add an attribute like this, just make sure the condition does what you want, and that that the HTML is outputted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use if condition in textbox -

```
<?php if($stock_count <= 0) { echo "disabled='true'"; } ?>
```

Here is the code inside textbox

```
<input name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" id="sale" value="CONCESSION PRODUCT SOLD" style="width:100%" <?php if($stock_count <= 0) { echo "disabled='true'"; } ?> onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>
```

Comment: I found more suitable the ternary operator here: ```<?php echo ($stock_count <= 0)? "disabled='true'" : ""; ?>```

Comment: yeah, we can use that but here no need else condition

Answer (score 0):

Add this somewhere in your php block

```
<?php $disable = ($stock_count>0) ? '' : 'disabled="disabled"'; ?>
```

And then in you html you can do this :

```
<input <?php echo $disabled; ?> name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" id="sale" value="CONCESSION PRODUCT SOLD" style="width:100%" onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $stock_count = 1; 
    $disabled = $stock_count <= 0 ? "disabled='disabled'" : "";

?>

<input name="button5" type="submit" id="sale" ... <?php echo $disabled; ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers are correct for this situation, but there is another way depending on what you need to do.

If there are more things to be done other than disabling for example, it may make sense to "echo" your php values directly into javascript variables then use js/jQuery to handle all manipulations.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myJsVar = '<?php echo $myPHPVar; ?>';
   // do js/jQuery conditions here to disable or whatever else you need
   ....
```